# Как отобразить пробелы в emacs?

Tags: emacs

В файл .emacs я добавил следующие строки как было показано [здесь](http://reangdblog.blogspot.com/2015/06/emacs_29.html):

`(setq whitespace-style '(face trailing tabs spaces lines newline empty
                         space-mark tab-mark newline-mark))
(set-face-attribute 'whitespace-space nil :background nil :foreground "#00FF00")
(set-face-attribute 'whitespace-newline nil :background nil :foreground "#0000FF")`

Но почему-то emacs ругается на вторую и третью строки

Comment: ну хоть бы текст ошибки привели

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом коде ты используешь символы `whitespace-space` и `whitespace-newline`, но они определены в пакете `whitespace`, который по умолчанию не загружается. Тебе надо добавить `(require 'whitespace)` перед этим кодом.